# Toolbar not displayed when segue back to tabviewcontroller (iOS Swift)

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, nstabview

I have a tabviewcontroller that has three tabs, park, location, and attractions. On the attractions page, annotations of attractions are populated on a mapview. when you click on the callout for the mapview, you can click on the annotation and it'll take you to a detailed viewcontroller of the given location. I have a toolbar at the top of the controller that segues from the detailViewController (not part of the tabviewcontroller parent) back to the attractions viewcontroller (is part of the tabviewcontroller parent). However, when i segue back, the attractions viewcontroller does not have the toolbar at the bottom. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is embed a navigation controller. You can do this by going to editor, embed, embed navigation controller. This allows you to use its built in toolbar to navigate forward and backward